# Htaccess error with capturing get variables AND trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, slash

I have the following in my .htaccess file

```
    # Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

    Options -Indexes


    # preserve bandwidth for PHP enabled servers
    <ifmodule mod_php4.c>
     php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
    </ifmodule>

    # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^faq/?$ faq.php
    RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php
    RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ portfolio.php?p=$1

            #Error Page___NOT found
    ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

My portfolio only contains the sections "celebrity","weddings" and "industrial"
i.e. only the following pages are valid portfolios:

```
    mysite.com/portfolio/celebrity
    mysite.com/portfolio/weddings
    mysite.com/portfolio/industrial
```

I'm having problems with the "portfolio" page in certain situations:  When i visit

```
    "mysite.com/portfolio/celebrity"
    "mysite.com/portfolio/weddings"
    "mysite.com/portfolio/industrial"
```

everything works fine.If, however, i visit

```
    "mysite.com/portfolio/celebrity/"
    "mysite.com/portfolio/weddings/"
    "mysite.com/portfolio/industrial/"
```

(notice the trailing slash),Firefox gives me the following error

```
    Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

I've tried replacing the last line with

```
    RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)/?$ portfolio.php?p=$1
```

which doesn't help either, and displays the aforementioned error.

Visiting

```
    "mysite.com/portfolio/some-non-existent-portfolio"
```

OR

```
    "mysite.com/portfolio/some-non-existent-portfolio/"
```

doesn't redirect to "notfound.php"

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: no, that doesn't solve the problem...any other ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, solved it thanks to this webpage : 
http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=167839.0

I changed the relevant line to

```
    RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ portfolio.php?p=$1
```

Now everything works perfectly, including showing 'notfound.php' when portfolio type visited is a non-existent one.  Hope this helps somebody.